# Where will Debug.WriteLine in C# output to when build release?

Tags: c#, debugging

I put a lot of Debug.WriteLine in my code for debug purposes. 
When I am ready to build for release, will these Debug.Write influence the release build, and where do they output to?

Comment: Thanks a lot to all who provided answers. They are all correct. But I can only select one answer. upvoted the rest. thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.debug(v=vs.110)):
"The ConditionalAttribute attribute is applied to the methods of Debug. Compilers that support ConditionalAttribute ignore calls to these methods unless "DEBUG" is defined as a conditional compilation symbol. Refer to a compiler's documentation to determine whether ConditionalAttribute is supported and the syntax for defining a conditional compilation symbol."

So if your release configuration does not include DEBUG symbol the Debug.WriteLine calls will be omitted during compilation and there will be no output.

Comment: If you're going to quote MSDN it's best to cite a URL.

Answer (score 19):

`Debug.WriteLine` is annotated with the `Conditional` attribute.  (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z9k5ydz.aspx))

The [ConditionalAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx) tells the compiler not to generate that code unless the `DEBUG` flag is supplied.

Answer (score 8):

If you switch them to [`Trace.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.writeline.aspx) you can define arbitrary listeners in the app/web.config file.

Comment: +1 because this is a preferable way to have content output via configuration. Although, it requires the `TRACE` flag to be defined at compilation *and* all messages are compiled into code regardless of the build type.  `Debug.WriteLine` should be used for messages you **don't** want in a Release build.

Answer (score 6):

Debug.Writeline is not compiled into release code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it will be compiled out.