# View Debug Messages in VS2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to debug an application in VS. In my code, I am trying to write to the debugger.

```
Code:
For value As Integer = 0 To 5
    Debug.WriteLine(Value)
Next
```

Where does it output during runtime? I have my Output Window open, but I don't see anything.
I am using Visual Studio 2010 Professional

Comment: The output window has a combobox where you have to select that you want to see debug output.

Comment: My combobox is selected as "Debug". One thing I am noticing when I add a breakpoint and step through each line, it skips the Debug.Write code.

Comment: It seems the code was compiled as release?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where will Debug.WriteLine in C# output to when build release?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936468/where-will-debug-writeline-in-c-sharp-output-to-when-build-release)

Comment: The compiler will not break on `Debug` statements, just Breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

The debug messages will be shown in the [**Immediate Window**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy(v=vs.140).aspx) (among a few others). It can be opened by pressing the keyboard combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>, or by the menu option `Debug > Windows > Immediate Window`.

Apart from your own debug messages, the Immediate Window displays a message when an exception is thrown, and can also be used to call methods or evaluate expressions at run-time. I've covered the latter in a [**previous answer of mine**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41321145/3740093).